# The basic structure of stack frames

Tags: assembly, stack, frame, x86-64, stack-frame

I'm currently playing around, examining stack frames, trying to get an idea of how this works. After reading a few articles that always explained that the general structure would be:

local vars     <--- `SP`       low address

old `BP`         <--- `BP`

ret addr
args                         high address

I have an example program that calls a function with three arguments and has two buffers as local variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int a, int b, int c);

int main()
{
        function(1, 2, 3);
        return 0;
}

void function(int a, int b, int c)
{
        char buffer1[5];
        char buffer2[10];
}
```

I took a look at the assembler code of the program and was surprised not to find what I expect when the function is called. I expected something along the lines of:

```
# The arguments are pushed onto the stack:
push 3
push 2
push 1
call function       # Pushes ret address onto stack and changes IP to function
...
# In function:
# Push old base pointer onto stack and set current base pointer to point to it
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp

# Reserve space for stack frame etc....
```

So that the structure of the frame, when executing the function, would be something like:

```
buffers   <--- SP           low address
old BP    <--- BP
ret Addr
1
2
3                           high address
```

But instead what happens is the following:

The function call:

```
    mov     edx, 3
    mov     esi, 2
    mov     edi, 1
    call    function
```

Why use the registers here when we can just push to the stack???
And in the actual function that we call:

```
    .cfi_startproc
    push    rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    mov     rbp, rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    sub     rsp, 48
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-36], edi
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-40], esi
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-44], edx
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR fs:40
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
    xor     eax, eax
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    xor     rax, QWORD PTR fs:40
    je      .L3
    call    __stack_chk_fail
```

As far as I can see, 48 bytes are reserved for the stack frame right? And afterwards, using the registers from the function call, the arguments to the function are copied to the end of the stack. So it would look something like this:

```
3            <--- SP
2
1
??
??
old BP       <--- BP
return Address
??
```

I assume the buffers are somewhere between the args and the old `BP`. But I'm really not sure where exactly...since they are both only 15 bytes in total and 48 bytes where reserved...won't there be a bunch of unused space in there?
Can someone help me outline what is happening here? Is this something that is processor dependant? I'm using an intel i7.

Cheers,
Brick

Comment: `won't there be a bunch of unused space in there?` its important to note that stack allocations will always be rounded to a multiple of the target architecture's word size. along with that, the ABI may also force alignment requirements (such as the 16byte requirement on x64), which may also increase the size.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues. First, the 3 arguments are passed by register because that's part of the ELF ABI specification. I'm not sure where the latest (x86-64) SysV ABI document is kept these days, (x86-64.org seems defunct). Agner Fog maintains a lot of excellent documentation, including one on [calling conventions](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf).

The stack allocation is complicated by the call to `__stack_check_fail`, which is added as a countermeasure to detect stack-smashing / buffer overruns. Part of the ABI also specifies that the stack must be 16-byte aligned prior to a function call. If you recompile with `-fno-stack-protector`, you'll get a better idea of what's going on.

Furthermore, because the function doesn't do anything, it's not a particularly good example. It stores the arguments (needlessly), requiring 12 bytes. `buffer1` and `buffer2` are probably 8-byte aligned, effectively requiring 8 and 16 bytes respectively, with possibly another 4 bytes to align them. I might be wrong on this - I haven't got the spec at hand. So that's either 36 or 40 bytes. Call alignment then requires a 16-byte alignment for 48 bytes.

I think it would be more instructive to turn off the stack protection and examine the stack frame for this leaf function, and consult the x86-64 ABI spec for the alignment requirements of local variables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather compiler dependant. You can try turning off optimization or flag function with an "extern" keyword (to force using default calling convencion).

Registers are used because this is much faster than sending arguments by stack.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Makes sense to use the registers in that case.

Still, I tried assembling it with 'gcc -O0 -S -masm=intel main.c' 
turning optimization off, but I still get the same result.

I take it, it's just a way of doing it. Still, I would like to know exactly how the stack frame is comprised in this case. Can anyone help me with that? I'm having trouble identifying the buffers in the stack frame...plus, wouldn't the addresses of the buffers also need to be stored on the stack somewhere?